# Ifelse condition over a mask

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a problem. Imagine I have a data set a:

```
     row1 row2 row3
col1  2    3    5
col2  5    3    4
col3  3    1    6
```

And I have a mask, which identifies those entries, which should be transformated:

```
     row1 row2 row3
col1  T    F    F
col2  F    F    T
col3  F    T    F
```

So basically, I want all of the entries which are labelled as TRUE (T) be replaced by their value they have right now minus the value out of another dataset b:

```
     row1 row2 row3
col1  1    4    8
col2  4    1    1
col3  6    2    7
```

So the result should be:

```
     row1 row2 row3
col1  1    3    5
col2  5    3    3
col3  3   -1    6
```

What i tried was:

```
new_dataset <- ifelse(Mask == 'FALSE', a, a - b)
```

However, I end up with a list instead of a data frame. I know, that is because R creates every entry within the list by the total dataset a or (a-b). But how can I handle this?

Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `a - b * mask`:

```
a - b * mask
#      row1 row2 row3
# col1    1    3    5
# col2    5    3    3
# col3    3   -1    6
```

It works for both data frames and matrices:

```
as.data.frame(a) - as.data.frame(b) * as.data.frame(mask)
#      row1 row2 row3
# col1    1    3    5
# col2    5    3    3
# col3    3   -1    6

as.matrix(a) - as.matrix(b) * as.matrix(mask)
#      row1 row2 row3
# col1    1    3    5
# col2    5    3    3
# col3    3   -1    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the datasets are `data.frame`s, we convert the 'i1' (i.e. the TRUE/FALSE dataset to `matrix`, use that to extract the elements from 'a' and 'b', subtract the corresponding elements and assign it to the 'a' that is TRUE for 'i1'.

```
i2 <- as.matrix(i1)
a[i2] <- a[i2] - b[i2]
a
#     row1 row2 row3
#col1    1    3    5
#col2    5    3    3
#col3    3   -1    6
```

---

Or if the datasets are really big, then looping through columns might be more efficient.  We can use `mapply` to replace the corresponding columns of 'a' with 'b' based on the index column in 'i1'

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) {x[z] <- x[z] - y[z]; x}, a, b, i1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way around:

```
res <- a-b
w <- which(mask==F, arr.ind = T)
res[w] <- a[w]
```

OR

```
res <- a
res[mask] <- a[mask]-b[mask]

#      row1 row2 row3
# col1    1    3    5
# col2    5    3    3
# col3    3   -1    6
```

`w` contains those values in `a` that remain unchanged.